# Using caret train(): Why is the direct prediction result worse than 10-fold cross validation?

Tags: r, machine-learning, lm, cross-validation, r-caret

I want to use caret to build a linear regression model estimated by 10-fold cross validation result.

```
fitControl <- trainControl(## 10-fold CV
  method = "repeatedcv",
  number = 10,
  ## repeated ten times
  repeats = 10,
  savePredictions=T)

Fit1 <- train(X_B,Y_B,
        method = "glm",
        trControl = fitControl)

> Fit1

Generalized Linear Model 

23 samples
 4 predictor

No pre-processing
Resampling: Cross-Validated (10 fold, repeated 10 times) 

Summary of sample sizes: 21, 20, 21, 21, 21, 21, ... 

Resampling results

  RMSE       Rsquared   RMSE SD     Rsquared SD
  0.1521155  0.8742447  0.07348565  0.2732692
```

It seems I got a good prediction result. But when compared with observation,

```
> cor(Fit1$finalModel$fitted.values,Y_B)
[1] 0.6307828
```

The result is very different with validation result.
I would really appreciate some help, thank you in advance.

This is the data I used
X_B

```
82  67.5    89  540
82  79.4    33  33
82  66.6    43  231
66.6    82  55  51
82  66.6    116 231
66.6    53  55  151
67.5    66.2    28  28
82  82  120 116
82  67.5    53  203
66.6    82  36  32
82  66.6    235 229
66.6    82  24  23
82  82  130 381
82  66.6    38  245
82  47.3    70  62
82  66.6    132 262
68.4    82  25  24
82  67.5    103 244
65.6    82  34  28
82  66.6    73  225
67.5    53  55  54
82  82  213 287
66.6    82  65  61
```

Y_B

```
1.18650088809947
1.07726763717805
0.703157894736842
1.05601659751037
1.08866442199776
0.955510616784631
0.77390180878553
1.00677200902935
0.870726495726496
0.730769230769231
0.804239401496259
0.897186147186147
1.3880764904387
0.861434108527132
0.755862068965517
0.996685082872928
0.888789237668161
0.894220283533261
0.931395348837209
0.97422126745435
0.84297520661157
0.995975855130785
1.23547717842324
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks that in your case the amount of cross validations is close to the amount of rows. The amount of training examples in each cross validation are so small that the predictive value of those cross validations decrease,hence the lower accuracy.